# Does a C++ Windows Forms Application require .NET Framework?

Tags: windows, forms, frameworks, c++-cli

**Does a C++ Windows Forms Application require .NET Framework?**

It seems that it does because it imports **"System::Forms"** but I just want be 100% sure. I tried opening it with **depends** and it looks like it imports the usual C++ dll's but there is nothing about the framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Forms are part of the .NET Framework, so yes.

If you don't want the .NET framework as a dependency you need to use native Win32 API or MFC.
You could also use a third party library like Trolltech's Qt.

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html) has a good FAQ that covers why:

> Will Dependency Walker work with COM,
>   Visual Basic, or .NET modules?
>
> Yes.
>   Dependency Walker will work with any
>   32-bit or 64-bit Windows module,
>   regardless of what language was used
>   to develop it.  However, many
>   languages have their own way to
>   specify dependency relationships
>   between modules.  For example, COM
>   modules may have embedded type
>   libraries and registration information
>   in the registry, and .NET modules may
>   use .NET assemblies.  These techniques
>   are all implemented as layers above
>   the core Windows API.  In the end,
>   these layers still need to call down
>   to the core Windows functions like
>   LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to do
>   the actual work.  It is at this core
>   level that Dependency Walker
>   understands what is going on.  So,
>   while Dependency Walker may not
>   understand all the language specific
>   complexities of your application, it
>   will still be able to track all module
>   activity at a core Windows API level.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you are doing .Net Windows forms development as opposed to say Windows with MFC.

Answer (score 1):

By defnition, anything classified as Windows Forms requires the .NET Framework, yes.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms):

> Windows Forms is the name given to the
>   graphical application programming
>   interface (API) included as a part of
>   Microsoft's .NET Framework,

Answer (score 0):

You can use native windows with the Windows API from C or C++ and avoid the need for the .NET framework